# jquery bind , function(e)

Tags: jquery

In [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), what does the following do?

```
   $("#ivid1").bind("pageshow", function (e) { 

        // Do something.
    });
```

In particular, what is `bind`, `pageshow` and `function(e)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It binds a custom event `pageshow` to an element with id `#ivid1` and defining a handler (`function (e) {.. }` )for that event.

Later you can trigger this event like below,

```
$("#ivid1").trigger('pageshow')
```

> **Note:** As [Halcyon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131011/297641) and Josh Davenport (see comments) pointed out, it depends on the context and where it is being used.

Comment: To further explain, `pageshow` is a jquery mobile event. See: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: @JoshDavenport It may be, but it can also be a custom event. Since OP never mentioned about mobile, I am not going to assume it is mobile events.

Answer (score 0):

This binds a `pageshow` event to the `#ivid1` element.  When `pageshow` (whatever it may be) is triggered on `#ivid1`, probably through some mechanism of the browser, the function that is bound is executed.

I don't know what `pageshow` is, but apparently it's relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

"pageshow" is a string literal that refers to the OnPageShow JavaScript event. This is new to HTML 5 and therefore has some browser support right now. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp). The function (e) is syntax for calling an anonymous function and passing in an event argument.